# increase-memory-limit npm package not working with run-node npm package

Tags: node.js, cypress, npm-scripts, husky

I have added "increase-memory-limit" package some time back to increase the node memory and fix heap out of memory issue.

I recently introduced cypress to the code base for E2E testing as a pre-commit process and could see that "run-node" package has been installed as his dependency.

After this i am getting following error or run git commit

desktone/node_modules/run-node/run-node: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `('
desktone/node_modules/run-node/run-node: line 26:`has_node --max-old-space-size=2048() {'

Not sure how to fix the same.

I have following in my package.json for increasing node memory limit

```
  "scripts": {
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=2048 increase-memory-limit"
   }
```